# Runtime error, unable to determine the cause

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary

I'm implementing the abstract data type Map for my algorithms class, and we're asked to implement it using 2 arrays.

I have done the implementation last night and everything worked fine(when we send the assignment online it is tested using autotests), and it passed every test. 
Then I needed to implement it using binary search, and I did that.

This morning when I ran the code it gave me a runtime error and I think my copy constructor is the cause, because when I commented it out, the code worked fine, yet my copy constructor is exactly as my tutor implemented it.

Here is the code it crashes on:

```
    ArrayMap<string,string> m;
    string s1("Sarajevo"), s2("Zagreb");
    m[s1] = "BiH";
    m[s2] = "Hrvatska";
    {
    ArrayMap<string,string> m2(m);
    ArrayMap<string,string> m3;
    m3=m;
    m.empty(s1);
    cout << m2.numOfElements() << " ";
    cout << m2[s1] << " ";
    cout << m3.numOfElements() << " ";
    cout << m3[s1] << " ";
    }
    cout << m.numOfElements();
    cout << " '" << m[s1] << "' ";
    m.obrisi();
    cout << m.numOfElements();
    cout << " '" << m[s2] << "'";
```

And here is the constructor:

```
   ArrayMap(const NizMapa<TypeOfKey, TypeOfValue>& rhs){

   _capacity = rhs._capacity;
   _numOfElements = rhs._numOfElements;

   _arrayK = new TypeOfKey[_capacity];
   _arrayV = new TypeOfValue[_capacity];

    for(int i = 0; i<_numOfElements; i++){
        _arrayK[i] = rhs._arrayK[i];
        _arrayV[i] = rhs._arrayV[i];
    }

    }
```

EDIT:

SSCE

```
  ArrayMap<string,string> m;
  string s1("Sarajevo"), s2("Zagreb");
  m[s1] = "BiH";
  m[s2] = "Hrvatska";
  ArrayMap<string,string> m2(m);

  cout << m2[s1] << " " << m2.numOfElements();
  /* When I do just this it works fine, but when combined with others it crashes the            program*/
```

EDIT: http://pastebin.com/vXdBTs4n
This is the class implementation:
NizMapa is ArrayMap
_kapacitet is _capacity
_brojE is _numOfElements
TipKljuca is TypeOfKey
TipVrijednosti is TypeOfValue
methods:
obrisi is empty/delete(2 versions)

Note:this is NOT the binary search version, it's the sequential search one. If any additional info is needed please ask, this is important. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The exact error would be fine. ;)

Comment: This application has requested the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact...

Comment: Did you also implement `operator =`?

Comment: I would set a breakpoint in the copy constructor and inspect rhs._capacity and rhs._numOfElements

Comment: Yes, I have and it works fine, as in doesnt crash, and does its job.

Comment: If it does not crash when debugging but crashes when running without the debugger this may indicate that some member variable is not initialized. Perhaps you should cout them instead.

Comment: -1 for not showing what the error is and showing what you've tried

Comment: "doesn't crash" doesn't necessarily mean that it's correct. Bugs may not manifest themselves until much later.

Comment: why don't you debug it to find out where is the problem!?!

Answer (score 0):

Here you allocate using `_capacity`

```
_capacity = rhs._capacity;
_numOfElements = rhs._numOfElements;

_arrayK = new TypeOfKey[_capacity];
_arrayV = new TypeOfValue[_capacity];
```

burt here you use `_numOfElements`

```
for(int i = 0; i<_numOfElements; i++){
```

as the loop boundary. So these two probably don't match and your are writing beyond the array boundary if `_numOfElements` > `_capacity`.

Comment: Well capacity is the MAX number of elements, and numOfElements is the current number, I dont need to copy more elements I believe

Comment: Believing and debugging are two different things. :) And you didn't provide the full code, so this would be my guess.

Comment: Does this help at all:No breakpoint number 2.
In __cxa_throw () ()
Continuing...
Program exited with code 03.
Debugger finished with status 0

Comment: You should post an SSCE. You have somewhere a memory problem, and the posted code doesn't show it. Also when I say `debugging` I don't mean to let it run in the debugger, but stepping through, because this is what a debugger is for.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what is SSCE, and I can't find the definition on google, I'd post it right away

Comment: [SSCE](http://sscce.org/) is a small test program that exhibists the problem and is small enough that smebody else (we) can look at it, withtout digging through tons of unrelated code. And in many cases, creating the SSCE you may find the problem yourself.

Comment: I have done it, and apparently the copy constructor is not the problem, I tested it and it works fine, but when I try to run that code snippet in the main question, it crashes.

Comment: @Matsura we really are not going to be able to help with only the code you have provided since we have to guess. The bug is not in the code that you posted.

Comment: Ok I added that small program, and sorry but it's quite a big program, I'm doing my bestt

Comment: @Matsura Your small program does not help since we do not have the source code for ArrayMap.

Comment: The problem is my code(variable names etc), are all written in my language and it's too big to change every single one. I will post a link to pastebin.